# Hide div attribute from browser Inspect element

Tags: jquery

I went for an interview and they asked me a very tricky question.

The question was I have an attribute in a div(eg `rel`) and I am adding some value to rel with jQuery, I want to hide it so that user cannot see this value (or attribute) even from browser's inspect tool (or developer tool).

How can I do this or is this not possible in jQuery? My answer was its not possible.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - The example was still visible *in the inspector*.  I still think this is not possible, unless you use the `data` system, but that is not consistent with the specific example of `rel` provided here.

Comment: @cale_b Agreed bro... I first thought using `data` it was possible.